# how lowmemorykiller is invoked from kswapd process?

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel

As far as I can understand lowmemorykiller register itself to the shrinker_list.
When kswapd process comes in to picture when number of free pages reached below a threshold value.
But I am not able to understand how kswapd process invoke lowmemorykiller from shrinker_list.
Any help will be appreciated.(exact code point)

Thank you ,
Pradeep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [`struct shrinker`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/shrinker.h#L48). It is registered with `register_shrinker()`. It is defined in [mm/vmscan](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/vmscan.c#L186) and adds shrinker to `shrinker_list`. Then `shrink_slab()` calls [`shrink_slab_node()`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/vmscan.c#L227) for each shrinker, which in turn calls shrinker's `count_objects()` and `scan_objects()`.